# Prove that linear transformation is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $0_n$ denote the zero map $0_n:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $T : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map. Show that if
$T^k = 0_k$ for some $k$, then $T^n = 0_n$.

Comment: Cayley Hamilton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cayley-Hamilton theorem is probably the quickest, although this theorem itself is not so easy to prove.

---

For a more elementary method, you might want to show the following first:

> Let $A$ be a nilpotent $n \times n$ real matrix, such that $A^m = 0$ but $A^{m-1}\neq 0$. For an $v$ such that $A^{m-1}v \neq 0$, then the $m$ vectors $v, Av, A^2v, ..., A^{m-1}v$ are linearly independent.

To get an idea of the proof, suppose we have a linear combination:
$$c_0v+c_1Av+...+c_{m-1}A^{m-1}v=0$$
Multiply both sides by $A^{m-1}$ to obtain $c_0=0$. Continue to do so we can show all coefficients are zeroes.

---

Back to the question, if we have $A^n \neq 0$, then by result above, we obtain more than $n$ vectors that are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: thanks for the solution but I have a small doubt.

Since the roles of the coefficients is not entirely symmetric due to A^0, A^1, .... A^(m - 1) terms, how can I prove the rest of the coefficients to be zero. I was able to prove c_0=0 but not able to figure out how the rest of coeffiecients will be zero?

Comment: Do I multiple by A^(m-2) for the next step and assume c_0=0 and thereby proof c_1 = 0?

Comment: @Charles Yes, exactly.